# Extract table data from a pdf

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a pdf like this: [image: pdf]

I am using [pdf2json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf2json) to extract the text. The result is something like this:

```
`QUANT
ITY
ITEM CODEDESCRIPTIONUNIT PRICE
(inc-GST)
DISC %TOTAL PRICE(inc-GST)
0.2SPISALT1TATA SALT 1 KG *25 PC$20.00$4.00
----------------Page (0) Break----------------
"`
```

But using this, I cannot find which text belongs to which column in the pdf table. How do I extract text in proper format

Code to extract using the library:

```
    let pdfParser = new PDFParser(this, 1);
      pdfParser.loadPDF('./uploads/filename.pdf');
      pdfParser.on('pdfParser_dataError', errData => console.error(errData.parserError));
      pdfParser.on('pdfParser_dataReady', pdfData => {
    const raw = pdfParser.getRawTextContent();
    fs.writeFile('./uploads/fields.json', raw, function() {
      console.log('written?');
    });
    res.json({ raw });
```

Comment: Ciao, you are using `getRawTextContent()` that returns a string. If you use `getAllFieldsTypes()` what's the output?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito it's am empty array

Comment: Ouch! so you have to work with string split! Not only but as I can see thare isn't a fixed char delimitator between values! How to solve that? Can we define some rules? For example, last 2 values start always with $. Ok this is esay. Item code is always 8 digits? Quantity is always a number with 1 decimal?